# How to verify response body as a test in postman

Tags: javascript, api-testing, rest-api, postman

I want to verify the response data as a test using `Postman`.  For example, given the response below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
  }
}
```

How do I verify this response body as a test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Mache says, you search for each value.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("Verify Json values", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData.data.id).is.to.equal(2); 
    pm.expect(jsonData.data.first_name).is.to.equal("Janet"); 
    pm.expect(jsonData.data.last_name).is.to.equal("Weaver"); 
    // and so on and so on
});
```

**The better option:**

Create test cases for each assertion

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("Verify data ID", function () { 
        pm.expect(jsonData.data.id).is.to.equal(2); 
    });
pm.test("Verify first_name", function () { 
        pm.expect(jsonData.data.first_name).is.to.equal("Janet"); 
    });
pm.test("Verify last_name", function () { 
        pm.expect(jsonData.data.last_name).is.to.equal("Weaver"); 
    });
```

**Another option**

This will give you a better view on what actually went wrong or is not present on your json response body.

If you really wish to compare the full body, you can create a variable with the expected outcome in a pre-request script like so:

```
var expectedJsonBody =
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
  }
}

pm.environment.set("address", JSON.stringify(expectedJsonBody));
```

in your request test, you compare the response body with the variable.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer from @decypher
Grouped tests will fail if only one test fails
Individual pm.tests will create a higher number of tests in the reports

But you can add a try/catch for each check within a test case like this, and it would throw the error and carry on with subsequent tests;

```
pm.test("API response contains the expected fields", () => {

const response = pm.response.json(); 

//Test to FAIL
try{pm.expect(response).to.have.nested.property("category.name", "WRONG DATA");  
}catch(e){pm.test("A Test Failed", () => {throw new Error(e.message)});}

//Test to PASS
try{pm.expect(response).to.have.nested.property("category.id", 0);
}catch(e){pm.test("A Test Failed", () => {throw new Error(e.message)});}

//Test to PASS
try{pm.expect(response).to.have.property("id", 0);
}catch(e){pm.test("A Test Failed", () => {throw new Error(e.message)});}

//Test to FAIL
try{pm.expect(response).to.have.property("name", "WRONG DATA");
}catch(e){pm.test("A Test Failed", () => {throw new Error(e.message)});}

//Test to PASS
try{pm.expect(response).to.have.property("status", "available");
}catch(e){pm.test("A Test Failed", () => {throw new Error(e.message)});}

});
```

2 tests fail and the rest pass.

Answer (score 1):

After the [obvious - Status code is 2xx](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/) you need to add tests based on [content](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts/):

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("Verify first_name", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData.first_name).is.to.equal("Janet"); 
});
```

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645665/how-to-test-response-contains-a-particular-key-and-value-in-postman-test)

Comment: And for a more complete answer for testing in Postman https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts/

Comment: Hi @Mache... I want to verify full response body. Strings can validate using snippets .but i'm finding a way to write a test when consist url and numbers

Answer (score 1):

What if the response body returns few id's? few users? how can I test the response to find the exact user I am looking for in the response body? Let's say there is 16 users in the response and only one has first_name: Paul, I want to test if there is a user with Paul as a first_name and return his id? This keep testing only first user.

pm.test('Find duplicates', () => {
var expectedValue = data.FirstName;
const responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.response.to.have.body(expectedValue);

});

Comment: Hi moni, if you have a question, you should [Ask a new question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).